# Patch a module.object with python

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

Hello I'm trying the following test scenario

```
def test_main(monkeypatch):
  with patch("library.mockme.MockMe") as mock:
    message = MainObejct().message()
    assert message == "Mock me"
```

MainObject implementation

```
from library.mockme import MockMe

class MainObejct():
  def __init__(self):
    self.mock_me = MockMe()

  def message(self):
    return self.mock_me.message
```

The problem here is that the **MockMe** object is not patched... but if I change the import to `from library import mockme.MockMe` it actually works, is there a way to make it work with my original implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Hi this is all about where and what to patch. In your example you are mocking the `MockMe` class in the the `mockme` module. You need to mock the class that is imported into your `main.py` module. Have a look at [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) in the Python docs.

Hope this helps!

`test_main.py`

```py
from main import MainObejct


def test_main(mocker):
    m_mockerme = mocker.patch("main.MockMe")
    m_mockerme.return_value.hello.return_value = "goodbye"
    message = MainObejct().message()
    assert message == "goodbye"
```

`main.py`

```py
from library.mockme import MockMe


class MainObejct:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mock_me = MockMe()

    def message(self):
        return self.mock_me.hello()
```

`library/mockme.py`

```py
class MockMe:
    def hello(self):
        return "hello"
```

Comment: @AlvinEstrada if it answers your question, you should accept and upvote it, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers